# How do I position my navbar?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to learn bootstrap and so far it has been very fun. I have been stuck on this problem for a while, I want to space my navbar just two fifths of the screen. I think it will look a lot nicer if it is spaced that way but I haven't been able to find a solution. I was wondering if there is any way of doing that.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
    </button>     
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><strong>Website</strong></a>
  </div>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="products.html">Products</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

[image: Present navbar]
[image: Desired navbar]

Comment: If you change `container-fluid` to `container` it will use bootstraps default max width. Otherwise add `width: 40%; margin: 0px auto;` to the `navbar-header` div. This will make it 40% of the screen (2/5ths) and centered. Is that what you want? I think you could add a `<div class="container">` around the elements inside the `navbar-header` too. Not sure about that.,

Comment: This is a classic example of RTFM. Haha, I actually can use it here :)

Answer (score -1):

You can create a css class:

```
.adjust-margins-container{
    margin-left: 30%;
}
```

and then add the class to:

```
<div class="container-fluid adjust-margins-container">
```

[bootply example](http://www.bootply.com/yHa6AySxBc)